# Internet explorer 8 scrolling bug jumping at the bottom of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, internet-explorer-8, joomla3.0

---

I have a page built with Bootstrap, it runs ok in all browsers except for Internet explorer 8.

When viewing the page on that browser if i scroll all the way down I can't see the bottom of the page because the scroll jumps up (about 200px) automatically.

Searching the web I found out some solutions, but they need the final user to change the browser configurations, that's not good..

I already deactivated all scripts created by me, but it didn't help it seems a internet explorer bug. It's a Joomla 3 site.

Comment: I experience this problem in Chrome, still, in J! 3.3.6 using the default admin template. I can't believe the J! team haven't resolved it yet.

Comment: Do you have widgetkit? If you have try to remove it from your page. I'll post the CSS solution later if you have this component... I already asked them to solve this, but they say they don't support IE8 it just needs 1 CSS rule :/

Comment: I don't use widgetkit. I'm referring to fairly basic installations involving Akeeba, JCE, and one or two other common extensions.

Comment: My solution was the one I posted, now it does not happen. I'm using blank template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who has Widgetkit this solves the issue on IE8.

```
.wk-slideshow .slides li{ /*Autoscroll fix for ie8*/
    position: relative !important;
}
```